# Multiprocessing share array

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How i can share an array as in the code below with an array and not a single value (in this example there is a counter as you can see)?

How i can append and remove elements from the array?

```
class mp_counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = multiprocessing.Value('i', initval)
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value += 1

    def decrement(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value -= 1

    def value(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.val.value

counter = mp_counter(0)
proc = threading.Thread(target=start_processes,kwargs={"counter":counter})
proc.daemon = True
proc.start()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What about the `Queue`? Check out this example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: What about shared arrays: `shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, 10)
shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code I'm +1 the whole array.
Is that what you want?

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import threading

import numpy as np


class mp_counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, initval)
        self.val = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val += 1

    def decrement(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val -= 1

    def value(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.val

def start_processes(counter):
    print("Before:", counter)
    m = mp_counter(counter)
    m.increment()
    print("After: ", m.value())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = [1., 2., 3., 4.]
    proc = threading.Thread(target=start_processes,kwargs={"counter":counter})
    proc.daemon = True
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```

The output is:

```
Before: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
After:  [ 2.  3.  4.  5.]
```

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

check out **from multiprocessing import Array**.  Array has a "lock" argument that has a default of True for thread safe reason.  another option would be **from multiprocessing import RawArray** which does not have "lock" built in.

```
from multiprocessing import Array, Process
import numpy as np

def worker(shared_arr, proc_number):
    shared_arr[proc_number] = 1

shared_arr = Array('f', 4)
print("initialArray:", np.array(shared_arr))
# will print [ 0. 0. 0. 0.]

num_procs = 2
processes = []
for proc_number in range(2):
    p = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(shared_arr, proc_number,))
    p.daemon = True
    processes.append(p)
[p.start() for p in processes]
[p.join() for p in processes]

print("results:", np.array(shared_arr))
# will print [ 1. 1. 0. 0. ]
```